# why javascript cant find element?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why buy javascript say my div is null.

this the javascript code:

```
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
box.style.height= box.innerText;
```

and this is the HTML:

```
 <html>
  <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="classStyle.css">
   </head>
     </head>
     <body onmousemove="search()">

     <script src="java.js"></script>

     <center>
      <div id="header">Fantasy class</div>  
       <div id="box">50%</div>
     <div type=buttom> יצירת ליגה</div>
     </center>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: move your script tag to just above the closing of `body` tag

Comment: if the code is in `java.js`, then it's running *too early* ... by the way .. `div type=buttom`? div's don't have a "type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tag appears *before* the div id="box". Therefore, it is run before that div is created, and returns null.
To fix this, try moving the script tag under the div.

Comment: Please try not to answer obvious duplicates